# Why does not print the number in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, dos

I'm trying to make a program in assembler about Fibonacci secuence, but when I try to print out the number, prints symbols. I run out of ideas. What am I doing wrong?

This is the code I've done:

```
data segment
    a db 0
    b db 1
    c db ?
    n db 4
    msg1 db "Fibonacci: ", 10, 13, "$"
data ends

code segment
    assume cs:code, ds: data

    start:
        mov ax, data
        mov ds, ax 

        ;---------------------Print Message------------------------;

        mov dx, offset msg1
        mov ah, 9
        int 21h

        ;---------------------Fibonacci-------------------------------;

        fibonacci:
            mov ah, a
            mov bh, b
            add ah, bh
            mov c, ah
            loop fibonacci

            mov al, c
            add al, 30h
            mov ah, 2
            int 21h

        mov ax, 4c00h
        int 21h


    code ends
end start
```

And the output of that is "Fibonacci: weird symbols"

Comment: Study how the `loop` instruction works. Hint: it needs a count in `cx`. You don't have that. Also, learn to use a debugger.

Comment: Also, for `int21/ah=2`, the argument is expected in `cl`, not `al`.